# Row gets modified when form is opened in access vba

Tags: vba, ms-access

I need to prepare a screen that will work as a comments screen as used on Facebook. I have to prepare it on access form. Where User will enter the comments and the same should get stored in a table with PartNumber and ItemNumber. Also the recent Comments should be displayed on the same form.

I have prepared a form having Recordsource as my table where the comments needs to be saved. And written a click event where as user clicks the button the comments will get saved in table. But the prob is that without clicking that button if i type values in textbox and close the form still the table gets updated with value before click. Below is the code

```
Private Sub Post_cmnt_Click() 
    Me.RecordSource = "Part_GeneralPartComment" 
    Call FromForm_Add 
End Sub
```

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score 1):

Access automatically commits pending changes when a bound form is closed. If you want to prevent that from happening you can add the following code as the `On Close` event handler for the form:

```
Private Sub Form_Close()
On Error GoTo Form_Close_error
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdUndo
Exit Sub
Form_Close_error:
If Err.Number <> 2046 Then
    ' error was something other than "The command or action 'Undo' isn't available now."
    Err.Raise Err.Number
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.It worked but it asks that You Are about to delete 1 record when i close the form. Can that be skiped?
Also my forms header has 3 texboxes ItemNUmber PartNumber And Comment Text.PartNumber & ItemNumber are editable and initially picks a value from another form, later user can chnge it on their wish. The problem is When I open form and enter text in Comment text and then click to change rest 2 textbox the ntries with the previous values on those 2 texboxes get edited instead of adding a row and creating new record.On detail part of form d records must be displayed.Can u help